# how to execute a python (2.7) script from a c program in Windows

Tags: python, c, execution

I have been looking for this solution for some time and cannot find a solution. Some solutions have suggested using the "system" function in the . However, this suggestion is then always followed by 10 people saying never to use system as it lacks thread safety. Does anyone know how to do this?

Just some info: my python script gets and parses JSON from the internet, then creates a textfile, which the c program then uses. So, instead of having to run one, then the other, I want to run them both in succession from the C exe.

EDIT: Grammer

Comment: You may have two separate programs, one for fetching JSON and preparing data for it and another which takes the prepared data and produces some results. You may use, say, a batch file which glues things together. Thus you'll get a simplicity and, well, atomicity, which would allow you to construct a complex and flexible solutions just like Lego constructor does.

Comment: Have you considered doing it the other way around - i.e. calling into C functions from the Python script? This is the approach normally recommended in the Python community.

Comment: I had not, I will look into this instead. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use system function in c,c++

like this

```
 system("python ashouri.py");
```

or

use this code

```
  static PyObject *my_callback = NULL;

  static PyObject *
  my_set_callback(PyObject *dummy, PyObject *args)
  {
      PyObject *result = NULL;
      PyObject *temp;

      if (PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O:set_callback", &temp)) {
          if (!PyCallable_Check(temp)) {
              PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "parameter must be callable");
              return NULL;
          }
          Py_XINCREF(temp);         /* Add a reference to new callback */
          Py_XDECREF(my_callback);  /* Dispose of previous callback */
          my_callback = temp;       /* Remember new callback */
          /* Boilerplate to return "None" */
          Py_INCREF(Py_None);
          result = Py_None;
      }
      return result;
  }
```

Be Successfull

Comment: Which libraries do you have to include?